# How to display information of different table in twig symfony?

Tags: html, mysql, symfony, twig, inner-join

I need to display a table, for example 4 columns, I have a Palmares entity with different information.

How to put data from another sql table in the same loop, other information is linked with palmares.categorie.code Here is a part of my template with html.twig

```
{% for palmares in palmares %}
<tr>
 <td>{{palmares.categorie.code}}</td>
 <td>other information from another table</td>
 <td>{{palmares.compet.date |date("m/d/Y")}}</td>
 <td>{{palmares.compet.lieu}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT :

For example I have entity Palmares, Entity Categorie with variable $code integer. If I display palmares.categorie.code in twig it show me integer.

I have an other class OtherInformation with a variable code and it is linked with palmares.categorie.code

My PalmaresRepository have function like :

```
public function getPalmares(int $id)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->where('p.saison = :date')
            ->andWhere('p.club = :id')
            ->setParameter('date', date("Y"))
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: What is your "other information" and how is it retrieved ? Do you use some method like `findAll()` to get your palmares, or did you write a method in your `PalmaresRepository` ?

Comment: I write a method in my PalmaresRepository with createQueryBuilder()

Comment: Then if your information is linked to your palmares, can't you just `JOIN` on it so you can have it in TWIG with `{{ palmares.joinedField }}` ?

Comment: I don't know how to do Join in Symfony, how can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the information is linked to your palmares, you can simply join on it to get it simply in TWIG (below a code with query builder but you could as well use DQL if you prefer) :

```
/* /src/Repository/PalmaresRepository.php */
public function getPalmaresWithJoinedEntity()
{
  $qb = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->leftJoin('p.joinedField', 'j')
    ->addSelect('j')
  ;

  return $qb
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
  ;
}
```

```
/* /templates/your_template.html.twig */
{# ... #}
{{ palmares.joinedProperty.someField }}
```

Note that you are not forced to join in your repository to get your joined data, you can simply alter your template without joining, but you will face the N+1 problem (You will get an additional query per palmares, to get each joined property.)